# [Plugin: Wordpress NextGen Gallery]Album gallery thumbnail not linking to gallery

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I'm having a issue with my gallery thumbnail on the nextgen gallery album page not linking. Instead of using the given code:

```
    <div class="ngg-thumbnail">
       <a href="<?php echo $gallery->pagelink ?>"><img class="Thumb" alt="<?php echo     $gallery->title ?>" src="<?php echo $gallery->previewurl ?>"/></a>
    </div>
```

Located in the album-extend.php file.  To be able to use a larger thumbnail, see wordpress forum question  http://bit.ly/wmthxo/ I'm using the following code:

```
    <div class="ngg-thumbnail">
            <img alt="<?php echo $gallery->title ?>" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/gallery/albumthumbs/<?php echo $gallery->gid ?>.jpg" />
    </div>
```

The results of this can be seen at:  http://fineart3/chuprinacreative.com.  Please note; only the Forgotten Music image has been placed.

When clicking on the title Forgotten Music I am successfully taken to that page. Unfortunately when mousing over the image I get the mouseover effect but clicking on it does not bring me to the page, which it should.  What have I missed, what am I doing wrong.  Any help would gratefully be appreciated.

PChuprina

Comment: hi you should accept answers if you ask a question or reject them with a reason!

Answer (score 0):

hi the second bit of code is missing an A link, simply I think something like :

pagelink ?>"> aaround the image would work?